# Collect and aggregate jacoco results from multiple Gradle build steps in TeamCity 10

Tags: gradle, teamcity, jacoco, monorepo

**I have the following setup:**

I have a monorepo with multiple, independent Gradle based builds inside. I added one build step for each project in the repo, using each subdirectory as working directory of that build. I use the jacoco enhancer from TC to generate reports of the junit4 test runs of each project.

**What currently happens:**

Only the report of the last build step is kept and made the one that is shown in the build overview. I can see in the logs, that all jacoco reports are generated as expected.

**I'd like to achieve the following:**

I want all reports to be aggregated and treated as the overall coverage of the build.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution my self. Here is how I did it:

- Remove all jacoco options from any build step
- Add the gradle jacoco plugin to each project you want to have coverage generated for
- Add a command line build step at the very end of your build and fill it with something like the statement below

Please note, I use Kotlin in my project, please adjust your source path accordingly!

```
echo "##teamcity[jacocoReport dataPath='%teamcity.build.workingDir%/project1/build/jacoco/test.exec %teamcity.build.workingDir%/project2/build/jacoco/test.exec %teamcity.build.workingDir%/project3/build/jacoco/test.exec' includes='trivago.* sps.*' excludes='*Test *Fixture *Proto *Outer' sources='%teamcity.build.workingDir%/project1/src/main/kotlin %teamcity.build.workingDir%/project2/src/main/kotlin %teamcity.build.workingDir%/3/src/main/kotlin']"
```